# How to frame around Strong Tie Brackets

Tags: walls, framing

I'm about to start framing my carport to convert it into a garage. I'm unsure of the best way to deal with framing around these strong tie brackets.

What I imagine I'll need to do is cut a notch out of the top plate so it can go around the bracket without and be flush with the horizontal beam.

What is the best way to frame around my existing structural brackets?

**or**

Suggestions for alternatives?

[image: Bracket Close-Up]

[image: Brackets in context]

Answer (score 2):

You should get a permit to do this and the permitting authority will tell you what you can and cannot do. Even if the structure is sound and up to code as a carport, if you fill in walls this would change the wind loading. Contact building inspection.

Answer (score 0):

As the wall you're building is not structural notching is an acceptable solution.

An alternative would be to use scraps of thin (eg 1/2") wood as spacers to separate the top plate and the studs from the existing structure. I like engineered wood like MDF, OSB, and plywood for this because it doesn't split when you nail through it.

Comment: The wall is NOT structural...who are you kidding? The wind blows through the carport now. As soon as you put up a solid wall, it becomes a structural wall. You better install anchor bolts to the slab, top plates anchored to the roof system, sheathing nailed properly, etc. or you’ll find your “garage” in the next county.

Comment: it's not supporting the structure of the house (the existing posts do that)  therefore not structural, it's just a panel.

Comment: The posts hold the roof up and down. But when it becomes a wall, the wind will blow it over if you don’t create “shear walls”. The posts are not “shear” supports.